# What is the best way to update different properties?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm, restify

I'm building an `API` with `Restify` which is based on `Express`. I'm using `Typeorm` and I'm wondering what is the best way to update different properties which came from user input.

Essentially I have a route like this:

```
server.put('/users/:id', errorHandler(update));
```

which fire this method:

```
const update = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const user = { ...req.body, id: req.params.id } as User;
    res.send(await userService.update(user));
}
```

as you can see I used the spread operator to create an `User` entity. Then, inside `userService.update` I have the following:

```
export const update = async (user: User): Promise<User> => {
    const repository = getRepository(User);
    const entity = await repository.findOne({ id: user.id });
    if (!entity) throw new errors.ResourceNotFoundError(`There is no user with id of ${user.id}`);

    Object.assign(entity, user, { id: entity.id, chat_id: entity.chat_id, project_id: entity.project_id, deleted: false });
    return await repository.save(entity);
}
```

as you can see, I want prevent that the data provided by the `API` consumer will replace some important properties like: `id, chat_id, project_id, deleted`, so I used the method `Object.assign` to achieve this.

Is this a good way? What do you suggest for improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `update` method of typeorm like this, it will partially update the values that you give as a second argument.

```js
// this will find a user with id ${user.id} and will only 
// change the fields that is specified in the user object
await repository.update(user.id, user);

// check if updated for debugging 
const updatedUser = await repository.findOne(user.id);
console.log(updatedUser, null, 2)
```

If you want to create a new record of the existing user in db, then you only need to change it's id. To do that

1. Deep clone the object so there will be another user object with new reference
2. Remove `id` field from the deep cloned object and use `insert` afterwards

```js
// Deep clone user object
const clonedUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))
// Delete id field from the deep clone 
delete clonedUser.id;
// create a new user with different id
await repository.insert(clonedUser);
```

Comment: So I guess I should do the same for `insert`? Since, if I pass a data which contains `id`, the `save` method will try to update instead of insert. Could you please extend your answer for insert too, and show how to properly return the insert / updated data?

Comment: Do you want to add a new record or update an existing record?

Comment: I want add a new record, but imagine that the data provided contains also the `id` property, the `.save` method will try to update a record with the provided id.

Comment: My understanding is that you want a new record that is equal to old one, so the record you want to add is clone of the old one?

Comment: Yes, it's a possible case that I would like to manage. Basically: the database already contains a record with id 5, the user makes an API call passing a new record that has the field id 5. I would like to understand how I can insert the new record without considering the id passed by user, as the column is auto increment.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your important properties.

And pass the user id to the `update` method of your `userService`.

```
const { id, chat_id, project_id, deleted, ...user } = req.body;
const { id } = req.params;

res.send(await userService.update(id, user));
```

This will make sure `user` object don't have the properties(that is important).

And you can change your `update` method like below:

```js
export const update = (userId: string, user: User): Promise<User> => {
    return getRepository(User).update(userId, user);
}
```